# How to specify url params for google robot in sitemap.xml

Tags: sitemap, robots.txt

There are pages that need **login** for access. These are restricted, if any access is made they redirect to the login page. I would like to allow the google robot to access these pages with some specific url params. I was hoping to specify them in **sitemap.xml**.

Is this possible, and how ?  It is not a big deal if any hacker gets hold of it, as it will just display dummy information.  But it would be nice to restrict it from normal users.

Comment: Have you considered using url parameters?

Comment: The question was to add the url parameters in automatically for the robot.  I might just edit it above.  Also, it is sad that the answer has been removed.

Comment: The answer was deleted for being mostly a link only one.  The solution is found here 
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&ref_topic=6080646&rd=1